# Can i use Apples garbage collector on non cocoa programs?

Tags: macos, cocoa, garbage-collection

Apple provides it's own garbage collector implementation since 10.5.

I heared it is a conservative GC so i wonder if i can replace the Boehm-Weisser garbage collector in my pure C program. I'm using Boehm's GC for 7 years but it really lacks functionality when it comes to threads and using apples thread pool (aka Grand Central Dispatch) is impossible.

So how language dependent on Cocoa/Objective C is the garbage collector?

Answer (score 0):

from WWDC Videos Apple has said that libAuto (http://opensource.apple.com/source/libauto/libauto-180/) is language independent, so it can be used with just about anything.